# How to see when CosmosDB does rate limiting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

we're using CosmosDB as the DB for an API app.  When had an incident some time ago during which when I logged into the Azure portal, there was a message on the portal UI saying that CosmosDB was doing rate limiting, and that we should increase our RUs.

Does anyone know of a query that I can run in AppInsights after the fact to determine exactly when the rate limiting started and stopped ?  Or is there a place in the Azure portal where I can see the times when rate-limiting was happening?

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db#monitoring-from-azure-cosmos-db) help you? I assume that you wanna know when your cosmosdb database has high hits so I think cosmosdb metric could meet your requirement. And if you have other problems, pls add more details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When your consumed throughput has exceeded the provisioned throughput, you will get "Request rate too large" message or error code 429. You can use  [Azure Cosmos DB monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor-cosmos-db) to see the number of 429 exceptions to judge whether Cosmos DB does rate limiting. And you can increase the provisioned throughput to solve this problem.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-request-rate-too-large